Adding a new Bool property to Model causes crash
I added another Boolean property to a Model:
        @Model
        class Note {
            var id: UUID
            @Attribute(.unique) var title: String
            var drillDescrip: String
            var gamePractice: String
            var selfnotes: String
            var isCompleted: Bool
            var isWorking: Bool // <--- this is the new property added

(I didn't include the init here but it's in the Model)
I migrated to the new SchemaV3 (earlier migrations working just fine)
I haven't even used this property yet in my UIView anywhere and yet I get this SIGABRT on my Query:
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var context
    @Query(sort: [SortDescriptor(\Note.isCompleted), SortDescriptor(\Note.title)]) var drill: [Note]

{
    get {
        _drill.wrappedValue
    }
}

I decided to try not doing migration yet and just adding the property to current Schema and then just deleting app on simulator so that it sees this as the only version.
I haven't even used the property anywhere in my UIView and yet it still crashes with a SIGABRT.
This code unfolds and appears after my Query code. I did not originally type this in my code:
get {
    _drill.wrappedValue
}


I'm not accessing it. That bit of code appears when the sigabrt warning happens. It's not any code that I typed. The code "unfolds" and this text appears right under the Query statement when the crash happens.

Ah then I understand

I believe the property is being used under the hood directly even if you don’t access it. Have you tried to give it a default value?

Yes. It has a default value of "false" in the init of Model setup

I have done 2 other data migrations on the other Models that I have. Adding / deleting properties as things change. I have had no problems whatsoever. Now, all I'm doing is literally adding another Bool to the Notes model and things go haywire. It's such a minor addition.

The init is not where you give a default value, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79163616/simple-migration-in-swiftdata-does-not-work

But in the link you just sent, the default values are in the init. Also, I had followed P Hudson's directions back when I was learning about SwiftData and his examples suggested putting default values in the init.  https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftdata/defining-a-data-model-with-swiftdata

Ahh, wait. I just saw the answer in the post you shared. However, I don't think Paul Hudson had suggested doing it this way. I will try it the way you mentioned and see if that helps although my other models are done this way and they are working fine.

Did you see my answer in the question I linked to? The article from Paul you linked to has nothing do do with adding a property.

Sorry, I missed the question/answer at the top of this page. I did check the link. The link to P Hudson was about putting defaults in the init, not about adding properties. But the link you supplied was a fuller example about the default values. Thank you. It seemed silly at first but it does seem to work now. I still don't know why my other models worked when I hadn't done them this way before. Thank you again.
